# Count number of times a button was clicked in rails as global variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that sends a post request to an API. The API is a tmux session running eight different variations of a python scraper script on ports **:8000-8008** of the server.

Currently, I am unable to do more than one search at a time because I have no way of changing which port I send the request to without manually changing the port code. Thus we have to wait on the current script finishing, which takes about 5 minutes each time.

Is there a way of recording the button press so that every time a search is performed, we cycle through each script running on each of the eight ports **:8000-8008**?

So far I have tried changing the port number to a global variable and trying to iterate through the ports, however, even if I get this working it will run into problems with multiple users. Also, I will be splitting this function in two for a sidekiq session so passing data between the functions is going to cause problems.

```
 <%= form_tag leads_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

```
class Lead < ApplicationRecord


  def self.get_leads(params,current_user)

    
    response = HTTParty.post("http://super.secret.ip:8001",
    
      body: [ { "q" => "#{params}", "max_results" => 3, "max_reviews" => 3 } ].to_json)
  
  records = (response.parsed_response || []).map do |google_places_id, reviews|
    {
      google_places_id: google_places_id,
      website: reviews.any? ? reviews.first['website'] : nil,
      reviews: reviews.map { |review| { stars: review['stars'].to_f, text: review['text'] } },
      avg_stars: reviews.any? ? reviews.inject(0) { |sum, review| sum + review['stars'] }.to_f / reviews.size : 0
    }
  end.filter { |record| record[:website] }
    
  records.each do |record|
    @lead = Lead.create!(places_id: record[:google_places_id], website: record[:website], rating: record[:avg_stars], user_id: current_user )

    record[:reviews].each do |review|
      @lead.reviews.create!(stars: review[:stars], text: review[:text].gsub("'", "\\\\'"), lead_id: @lead.id)
    end   
  end   
  end    
  
  

end
```

Comment: _"The API is a tmux session running eight different variations of a python scraper script"_ – that sounds quite brittle. If the API is under your control, you should replace it with an actual HTTP server that can serve multiple requests on a single port.

Comment: It really seems to me you're trying to solve the wrong problem.